# Which Asp.net exceptions can do what?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, .net-4.0, exception, w3wp

If I write this code

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page_Load(sender, e);
    }
```

I get the an Error (endless recursion):

[image]

and the `w3wp.exe` process is terminated from `task manager`.

**Fine...**

however if i do:

```
throw new ApplicationException(); //or SystemException();
```

it appears in just a regular exception page. ( w3wp.exe is still up).

questions :

- what kind of exceptions causing the **w3wp.exe** to shutdown ?
- what kind of exceptions causing the **Application Pool** to shutdown ?

p.s.
*according to what ive just written  , please think about the following scenario : 
i can write a web page , host my site in a farm of sites , and i can terminate the whole w3wp.exe process by creating recursion ..... ( also others will have trouble)...*

Can you please answer my questions ?

thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the application log - exception details should show up there.

Comment: @moguzalp No. Also on non-debugging mode. but thats fine. I dont have true exception in production. i just want to understand which exceptions can terminate what....( just testing to learn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely the famous [`StackoverflowException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It's caused by an infinite loop since you're calling the method `Page_Load` again and again.

From MSDN:

> In prior versions of the .NET Framework, your application could catch
>   a StackOverflowException object (for example, to recover from
>   unbounded recursion). However, that practice is currently discouraged
>   because significant additional code is required to reliably catch a
>   stack overflow exception and continue program execution.
>
> Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, a StackOverflowException
>   object **cannot be caught by a try-catch block and the corresponding
>   process is terminated by default**. Consequently, users are advised to
>   write their code to detect and prevent a stack overflow. For example,
>   if your application depends on recursion, use a counter or a state
>   condition to terminate the recursive loop. Note that an application
>   that hosts the common language runtime (CLR) can specify that the CLR
>   unload the application domain where the stack overflow exception
>   occurs and let the corresponding process continue. For more
>   information, see ICLRPolicyManager Interface and Hosting Overview.

You may want to have a look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4802309/284240

Comment: hi tim yeah I know , but this is just 1 exception among many. i want  my mind to be orginized with : `WHICH EXCEPTION (their characteristics) CAN TEMINATE` : **1)AppPool  2)w3wp**

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `OutOfMemoryException` will have the same effect.

Comment: @volpav nope `Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.` w3wp.exe is still up.

Comment: (okay, now I'm just guessing) how about `AccessViolationException`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the exception is memory overflow. There are many ways how an application can cause this, there is no point to guess specific scenarios. I imaging good hosting providers should be protected from misbehaving applications.

Answer (score -3):

to add to the answers which alrdy are available. u cant bring down the whole process because every website in a server runs in a seperate AppDomain. so if ur code misbehaves only ur appdomain wud be killed.

Comment: Can you please try to keep the txt spch 2 a minmum?  lso prop caps wud b nice.