# Automatically reenabling ASP.NET service after failure in IIS 7 server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Due to exceptions in my web application (which i'm fixing now) the ASP.NET v4.0 service pool stops (and i have to start it again) and my question is... is there any way to configure the IIS server so if this happens it reenables the service pool again after some time?

Could this damage the server in any sense?
(the exceptions in this case i know are due to writing to a file from multiple threads at the same time but this issue i will solve it soon. I'm asking just in case new ones happen in the future because of other reasons).

Thanks in advance.

P.D. (I'm new to servers)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET application pool shutdown problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742122/asp-net-application-pool-shutdown-problem)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280886/how-to-config-application-pool-in-iis-7-5-automatically-re-start-when-it-was-sto

Comment: This is indeed duplicated, how can i close it?

Comment: @SaintJob2.0 Flag your question and a moderator will take care of it.